# AngularJS factory in a different file

Tags: angularjs

I am totally new to angularJS, so this is a first for me. I have initializes angular app, created a controller, and up until this point everything  works fine. Problem starts when i create a factory in a different file, then I do not know how to register it in a controller. When I reference factory to controller like i do, I get `Error: $injector:unpr
Unknown Provider`. What am I doing wrong?

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("appCtrl", function($http, appFactory) {
var that = this;
// Some stuff

}
```

This is factory in different file.

```
var app = angular.module("app");

app.factory("appFactory", function() {
var factory = {};
someData = [];


    factory.getData = function() {
        return someData;
  };
    return factory;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont create a module again. essentialy remove this line "var app = angular.module("app"); " from your factory file code. and create service using getter syntax. 
HTML FILE

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>title</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.js"> </script>
    <script src="app.js" /> </script>
    <script src="service.js" /> </script>

</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    {{text}}
</body>
```

Controller

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, myserv) {
    $scope.text = myserv.myFunc();
    });
```

Service / factory

```
    app.service('myserv', function() {
          this.myFunc = function () {
    return 'abc';
}
```

});

Comment: Hi, but if I remove the line, on what module will I create the factory? I think that I am retrieving pre-existing module with that line.

Comment: app is holding reference to he module "app" . it will work although declared in differnet file.

Comment: Ok, i still get the same error. Note that if I move factory code in the same file where my module is created and where controller is, everything works fine.

Comment: First, i do not see how your updated answer is different that my code. I still get the same message, it is like it do not see the module in the file where module is not created.

Comment: have you included the files in your html file?

Comment: Wow... That was it, it was not on my mind... I tried everything else. Thank you very much!!!